# Use Shaka player to display WebVTT captions or subtitles

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webvtt, shaka

I am using Shaka player to play HLS/DASH videos which works well.

I also have captions/subtitles as WebVTT files which are not referenced in the HLS/DASH manifests and are currently being loaded using separate `<track>` elements.

Currently I'm using native HTML5 methods for TextTracks (such as using `.oncuechange`) but that is awkward, and does not seem to work properly when there are multiple tracks. Since it seems Shaka player has its own parsing for tracks, I would like to switch to use *its* methods instead.

However I can't seem to see any documentation (something like https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html) for managing `<track>` elements. Is there any? Does anyone have any examples/codepen etc?

I'm not using the Shaka UI library and have my own 'CC' button, etc. I'd just like to control tracks using the Shaka functions rather than using my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Shaka player methods are documented here: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.Player.html.

External WebVTT files can be added with the `addTextTrackAsync()` method.
There are several methods related to text management in the docs, here are a few:

- `getTextTracks()` - returns a list of available text tracks
- `selectTextTrack(track)` - select specific track
- `setTextTrackVisibility(isVisible)` - enable or disable text displayer
- `selectTextLanguage()` - select specific language

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that approach is what I ended up going with as I couldn't use an existing <track> element with Shaka. Like you say, it (understandably) wants you to use its method to add the external track file. Not use an existing element. And that worked.